# Error when setting a click listener to a button

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to add an onClick() for a button declared in my activity_main layout but when I try to declare a button in the MainActivity.java, I get the error:

`The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)`

I've searched the error and found solutions stating to import the following `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` but that didn't fix the problem.

Can anyone spot what is wrong with my implementation?

Here is the code to declare the button and the accompanying case statement:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mClickButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);
        mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button mClickButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(this);



    }


//handle button clicks
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case  R.id.cameraBtn: {
                // start camera intent
                 Toast.makeText(this, "camera clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.searchBtn: {
                // search tree for matching debri
                 Toast.makeText(this, "search clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does Your Activity implements OnClickListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare that you are implementing the interface...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```